# Azure pipeline Running NUnit Tests

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

In my Azure Build Pipeline, Azure Test Task runs successfully but Tests have not been run.
[image: This is my test task]

Comment: In the test files put your tests dll, fore example: `*test.dll`

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk When I do that it says No test assemblies found matching the pattern: **Test.dll,!***TestAdapter.dll,!**\obj**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In my Azure Build Pipeline, Azure Test Task runs successfully but Tests have not been run.

Just like Shayki Abramczyk pointed out. You should specify the test dlls in the option **Test files**. And the default value should be:

```
**\*test*.dll
!**\*TestAdapter.dll
!**\obj\**
```

[image]

Check the document [Visual Studio Test task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/vstest?view=azure-devops) for some more details.

**Update:**

> When I do that it says No test assemblies found matching the pattern:
>   **Test.dll,!***TestAdapter.dll,!**\obj**

We need to build the solution before we test the dll files:

[image]

Hope this helps.